# How to add a module folder /tar.gz to nodes in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running pyspark in Ipython Notebook after doing following configuration

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook--NotebookApp.open_browser=False --NotebookApp.ip='*' --NotebookApp.port=8880"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
```

I am having a custom udf function, which makes use of a module called mzgeohash. But, I am getting module not found error, I guess this module might be missing in workers / nodes .I tried to add sc.addpyfile and all. But, what will be the effective way to add a cloned folder or tar.gz python module in this case , from Ipython .

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it, basically the idea is to create a zip of all the files in your module and pass it to sc.addPyFile() :

```
import dictconfig
import zipfile

def ziplib():
    libpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)                  # this should point to your packages directory 
    zippath = '/tmp/mylib-' + rand_str(6) + '.zip'      # some random filename in writable directory
    zf = zipfile.PyZipFile(zippath, mode='w')
    try:
        zf.debug = 3                                              # making it verbose, good for debugging 
        zf.writepy(libpath)
        return zippath                                             # return path to generated zip archive
    finally:
        zf.close()

...
zip_path = ziplib()                                               # generate zip archive containing your lib                            
sc.addPyFile(zip_path)                                       # add the entire archive to SparkContext
...
os.remove(zip_path)                                           # don't forget to remove temporary file, preferably in "finally" clause
```

Comment: Dharms - I tried this , but still the same error . No module named mzgeohash